# Javascript run function on setInterval and click

Tags: javascript, function, click, setinterval

Currently, I am running a function every five seconds.

`setInterval(function(){loadLog()},5000);`

However, how can I also run the function on demand (on the click of a button) without having to wait for the intervals?

I think that I MAY need to use something like clearInterval, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Are you asking how to run a function on a button click or how to stop the recurring interval?

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm asking how to run the function instantly (on the click of a button) while the setInterval is still running.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a click event handler:

```
 <button id="runLog">Run Now</button>
```

Javascript:

```
 document.getElementById("runLog").addEventListener("click", loadLog);
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than putting your function within the setInterval why don't you just write your function:

```
function loadLog() {
    //do something
};
```

and then call the function within the setInterval and also on the click event of your button:

```
setInterval(loadLog, 5000);
$('#button').click(loadLog);
```

at least this worked for me